# People starting to circumvent the best-practices tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-block-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-approach

Can we treat this to be just as subjective as the best-practices tag?

Comment: People are so resourceful, it's fascinating.

Comment: It's the worst practice, but the best one we've come up with yet.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not fully awake yet, but what does "Can we do the same subjective-issue" mean?

Comment: @Chris We don't allow "best practices" because it's subjective.

Comment: There aren't any questions left tagged `best-approach`.

Comment: Maybe someone will figure out someday that if people keep finding a way around this, there is probably a reason.  Fighting natural tendencies is a tough row to hoe.

Comment: @agf About 2 hours ago we had 9 of them since the 28th, someone must have changed it.

Comment: I'm sure, someone just went through and removed the tag, I guess. Wasn't me!

Answer (score 3):

I removed the tag from those questions. If no one else use this tag before end of day, it should after the new day be unreuseable for users who don't have enough rep to create tags. Blacklisting the tag should permanently prevent tag revival by users with enough tag-creation rep.

For reference (so that others can if necessary close them as *Not Constructive* or delete them if already closed), here are the questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620965/javascript-best-practice-data
- [Best practice for JS files being loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614849/best-practice-for-js-files-being-loaded)
- [Attaching a jQuery plugin on-the-fly for better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608736/attaching-a-jquery-plugin-on-the-fly-for-better-performance)
- [fragments best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607138/fragments-best-practice)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600762/is-there-any-good-reason-to-have-a-truly-schema-less-database-design
- [Best Practice for reserved words? renaming vars in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590342/best-practice-for-reserved-words-renaming-vars-in-rails)
- [Best practice for handling add/edit/delete forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583276/best-practice-for-handling-add-edit-delete-forms)

Answer (score 0):

These are almost all "make a list" type questions, so they should be closed. There is one that might be characterized as "review my code" instead, but that is also off-topic.

By all means baninate the tag, but in the mean time it provides a nice list of question that should be considered for closing.

Comment: Well, those questions might have a better change on other SE sites, like code review, *maybe* programmers, etc. Perhaps the answer is suggest the other sites?

Comment: Closing includes migration where that applies, and in any case closing and offering advice on better site selection are not mutually exclusive.